# Proving that a polynomial is the minimal polynomial using linear independence and not field theory.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, alternative-proof, minimal-polynomials

Here is the polynomial I want to prove that it is minimal:

$P(T) = T^6 -3xT^4 - 2xT^3 + 3x^2 T^2 - 6x^2T + (x^2 - x^3) = 0$

This was part of that question:

Let $F = \mathbb{R}(x) \cong \mathbb{R}^{(1)}$ and define $h \in \sqrt{F}$ by $h = x^{1/2} + x^{1/3}.$ Find and simplify the minimal polynomial $P(T) \in F(T)$ of $h$ over $F.$

Which I found its solution here:

[Why is this polynomial the minimal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3866518/why-is-this-polynomial-the-minimal)

And here is it:

You need some results from field theory here. First of all, the smallest field that contains $h$ and $\mathbb R(x)$, has degree (over $\mathbb R(x)$) equal to the minimal polynomial of $h$ over $\mathbb R(x)$. Therefore, if we can prove that this degree is at least $6$, we are done, since it is at most $6$ from the polynomial you produced.

You have already done some of the work. That is, when you wrote $h^3 + (3h-1)x = \sqrt x(3h^2+x)$, we get that $\sqrt x = \frac{h^3+(3h-1)x}{3h^2+x}$. So, any field that contains $h$ and $\mathbb R(x)$, also contains $\sqrt x$.

But then, $x^{\frac 13} = h - \sqrt x$, hence such a field also contains $x^{\frac 13}$.

Conclusion : The smallest field containing $h$ and $\mathbb R(x)$, also contains $x^{\frac 12}$ and $x^{\frac 13}$.

---

The minimal polynomial of $x^{\frac 12}$ over $\mathbb R(x)$ is the irreducible $f(T) = T^2-x$ (to show that this is the minimal polynomial is far easier than in our question). So we get $\mathbb R(x^{\frac 12})$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb R(x)$.

Now, the minimal polynomial of $x^{\frac 13}$ over $\mathbb R(x^{\frac 12})$ is $T^3 - (x^{\frac 12})^2 = 0$, which is again easily shown to be irreducible. It follows by field theory that the extension $R(x^{\frac 12} , x^{\frac 13})$ over $\mathbb R(x)$ has degree at least $2 \times 3 = 6$, as desired.

---

Edit : Over $\mathbb R(x)$, the polynomial $f(T) = T^2 - x$ is irreducible. Suppose that $f(T) = g(T)h(T)$ as polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb R(x)$. The $T$ degree of $f(T)$ is $2$, so that of $g$ and $h$ have to be $1$ so that they are non-trivial factors. Finally, $f(T) = (a(x)T + b(x))(c(x)T + d(x))$ for some polynomials $a,b,c,d$ of $x$.

Multiplying out, and comparing the $T$ coefficients, we get $a(x)c(x) = 1$, so both of $a(x)$ and $c(x)$ are constant. Then , $b(x)d(x) =-x$, so one of $b(x)$ or $d(x)$ is a constant, and the other is not. But then $ad + bc = 0$, so if three of them are constant the last one is also constant, which is a contradiction to the statement made in the previous sentence. It follows that such a non-trivial factorization can't exist.

---

Edit 2 : We want to show that the polynomial $T^3 - (x^{\frac 12})^2$ is irreducible over the field $\mathbb R(x^{\frac 12})$. For notational simplicity, let us take $B = x^{\frac 12}$.

Suppose $T^3 - B^2$ is reducible. Then by comparing $T$ degrees, there exist five polynomials in $B$, namely $a,b,c,d,e$ such that $$
T^3 - B^2 = (a(B)T + b(B)) (c(B)T^2 + d(B)T + e(B))
$$

> Why is this? Well, if you have a cubic polynomial(in $T$) which is factorizable, then it must break into two non-trivial factors, but the sum of their degrees must equal $3$. The only combination is $1+2 = 3$, because the degrees of these polynomials have to be positive but have to sum to $3$. One of these has degree $2$, which is of the form $c(B)T^2+d(B)T+e(B)$, and the other must have degree $1$, which is of the form $a(B)T+b(B)$.

now expand and compare coefficients of degree $T$ again. First, $a(B)c(B) = 1$ so both $a,c$ are constant. Next, $b(B)e(B) = -B^2$, so one of them is a constant, and the other is of $B$-degree $2$, or else both are of degree $1$.

Imagine $e$ is constant. Then $b$ is of $B$-degree $2$. We have $ad = bc$ from comparing $T^2$ coefficients, so to have equal $B$-degrees, $d$ is of $B$-degree $2$. Then comparing $T$ coefficients, $bd=ce$ which is clearly impossible by comparing $B$-degrees.

Imagine $b$ is constant. Then $e$ is of $B$-degree $2$. From $ad=bc$, it follows that $d$ is constant, but then $bd=ce$ can't happen since the $B$-degrees don't match.

Finally, if both of them have $B$ degree $1$, then from $ad=bc$ we know that $d$ is of $B$-degree $1$, and then $bd = ce$ cannot happen because the $B$-degrees don't match.

In summary, a factorization which is non-trivial, does not exist.

**My question is:I found the previous solution is complicated, and I was given a hint that the proof that the polynomial is minimal can be done by proving linear independence using the following definition https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixMinimalPolynomial.html , could anyone show me the details of this please? What matrix should I use? or just do the row reduction taking $x^{i}$  **

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. As for the irreducibility : I actually never looked to prove it in that question! I don't know criteria for irreducibility in such rings.

Comment: What about the criteria I mentioned in my question above? does it work?If so, how it works? could you please show me the details of this if you have time? @TeresaLisbon

Comment: Unfortunately the notion of minimal polynomial for a matrix, doesn't work the same way as a minimal polynomial of a field element. The minimal polynomial of a matrix *need not be irreducible*. Therefore none of that theory is actually helpful.

Comment: Ok @TeresaLisbon so your solution is the only correct one?

Comment: There is always the brute force solution : just like how I proved that $T^2-x$ and $T^3-B^2$ are irreducible by considering the degrees of their factors, I could do the same here as well. But I would have more cases, and each case would be harder. It would work, and would be another solution, but it is inelegant, and that is what makes you search for alternate solutions like the one I provide.

Comment: There's another thing I want to run by you : if it works I will post an answer. Basically, a polynomial in $T$ with coefficients in $\mathbb R[x]$, can also be thought of as a polynomial in $x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb R[T]$. So we may be ok comparing just $x$-degrees rather than $T$-degrees : since the $x$ degree of that polynomial is just $3$, the route could be easier.

Comment: Ok that is great, I hope it works and you can post an answer @TeresaLisbon